# Activation Energy in silicon etching

Tags: reaction-mechanism, reaction-control

I'm trying to understand what does activation energy means when we're talking about etching. Here's what I understand so far:

1. activation energy is the energy required by the system to undergo a chemical reaction. This means we need to input this much energy into the system for the chemical bonds to break (etch).
2. Higher activation energy means etching species have less energy and more thermal energy is needed for etching to occur.

Here's where I'm stumped. It's well known that (111) Si planes etch slower than (100) Si planes (I'm looking at KOH specifically but it goes for most other etchants too). BUT somehow Si(100) has a higher activation energy than (111). If the second point I mentioned above is correct, it should be the other way around i.e. (111) should have higher activation energy.

I'm also confused with why would the activation energy of a particular plane change with crystallographic orientation. One of the papers I read mentioned that Si(111) has a different activation energy for (100) orientation versus (110) orientation (see image below). They did provide a possible explanation for it but I don't seem to understand it fully. I think what they mean is that for (110) surface orientation of the silicon wafer, the number of atoms of the Si(111) plane exposed to the etchant is different than the number of (111) atoms exposed when the surface orientation is (100). Am I correct?

[image]

Comment: A link to your source would be a good thing. One thing to remember is that thermodynamics and kinetics are two different things. Further, looking at the diamond cubic crystal structure, the 111 planes (the close packing stacking direction) have the fewest unsatisfied bonds on the surface, and both 100 and 110 have ledges allowing for fast etching by kinks running along them.

Comment: Here's the link to the paper I cited above but I've read similar things in other papers too..https://doi.org/10.1016/0924-4247(94)00854-B

Comment: What you said makes sense and that was my understanding of the Anisotropy too. What doesn't make sense to me is the activation energy of (111) being low. Since (111) has fewest unsatisfied bonds it makes sense that it's harder to remove since it's more stable than (100) or (110) in a way. And activation energy is the amount of energy you need to ENTER into the system to remove atoms. So shouldn't (111) have higher activation energy than the other two planes?

Comment: Well, one issue is that, should you look layer-by-layer at the 111 bonding, there are two very different unsatisfied bond densities (either 1 or 3 per atom). No consider that the observed 'activation energy' may be some average value, not directly attributable to one single step.

Comment: From my understanding of etching, (111) has 1 unsatisfied bond, since the etching molecules attack the top layer.